# I want my coworker's git merge conflict markers to show up on my computer

Tags: git, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

Summary: I want the git conflict markers to show up on my computer so that I can resolve the conflicts in a text file. How can I do that?

Situation: 
I write a text file. 
I check in the text file. 
My coworker makes changes to the text file. 
I make significant changes to the text file. 
I check in the text file*. 
My coworker attempts to check in her version of the file. 
My coworker gets merge conflicts.

Both my coworker and I agree that it would be best if I went through the text file with the conflict markers and resolved the conflicts on my computer. I have searched, but have not found a way to convince git to give me a copy of the file with the conflict markers in it (ie., get git into a state where I can see and resolve the conflict). What steps would you take to make this happen?

Comment: The term "check-in" does not exist in git, and your scenario doesn't quite make sense.  You probably mean either pull or push.

Comment: You're trying to solve the wrong problem. The question should probably restated as "How do I help to resolve merge conflicts for changes other people did?" (@SLaks answer seems about right here)

Comment: Both very good comments, both. Yes, I meant commit, push, pull request, accept pull request. As you can probably tell, we're both git neophytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have your coworker commit his changes to his local HEAD (without your commit), then push to a new branch in your shared remote repo.

You can then pull from that branch to your local HEAD (with your commit) and you'll get the same merge conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: SLaks answer makes more sense for a quick fix. What's below is more involved and sets things up for a less master-repository-centric approach.

One way would probably be for you to pull the branch with her committed changes from her repository. That'd cause a merge on your end, and you could then resolve it. I presume you're both using the same branch, so assuming you have a remote on your end named `coworker` that points to her repository:

```
git pull coworker branchname
```

Setting up the remote depends on how your organization handles repositories. If all your coworker has is a normal local copy in their machine's filesystem, no `git` or `http` server making it remotely accessible, they may need to create a read-only network share for you to access through a `file` URL. If your organization has set up something like Github or Gitlab where developers have their own repositories on a server, setting up the remote is as simple as pointing it at the URL of your coworker's fork of the main repository. See the Git help for all the details, but the basic command syntax is:

```
git remote add coworker http://host.name/repository/path
```

replacing the URL there with the correct URL to your coworker's repository (eg. `file:///Q:/Path/To/Working/Copy` or `http://git.host.name/coworkerusername/repositoryname.git`).